# Force route order with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router-dom v6.
I want to force my app to follow an specific route order. This is my router file:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<DefaultLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
    <Route path="success" element={<Success />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
</Routes>
```

I want the route order to be like:

1. Only access checkout page from home
2. Only acess success page from checkout

I know that I can do this by using
`useEffect(() => {/*check if it came from where spected, else return last page*/}, [])`
inside my components with somekind of history, to see if it matches. But I want to know if there is a way of doing this in my router file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There isn't a way to just configure the routes to do this, you *will* need to check from *where* a user navigated from. This is basically a route protection question though. Create a custom `Link` component that sends the current location in route state, and a protected route component that checks this "from" location against an access list.

Example:

```
import { Link as BaseLink, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Link = ({ state, ...props }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  return (
    <BaseLink
      {...props}
      state={{
        ...state,
        from: pathname
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

...

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const AccessRoute = ({ accessFrom = [] }) => {
  const { pathname, state } = useLocation();
  const { from } = state || {};

  return [pathname, ...accessFrom].some((path) => path === from) ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to={from ?? "/"} replace />
  );
};
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<DefaultLayout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route element={<AccessRoute accessFrom={["/"]} />}>
      <Route path="checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<AccessRoute accessFrom={["/checkout"]} />}>
      <Route path="success" element={<Success />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit force-route-order-with-react-router]

Comment: I thought that there would be some kind of nesting routes that would do the trick, but I get your point, thanks.

Comment: @EmílioGularteKipper Nope, nesting routes is really just all about simplifying building routes and layouts using relative paths. In other words, it helps reduce code. The `Routes` component is the route path matching and rendering "gatekeeper", the `Route` component's themselves are [pretty dumb](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L139-L152), basically a container with an invariant check.